# before_filter and respond_to formats

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

In a controller in my Rails app, I can do this:

```
before_filter :login_required, :except => :index
```

But I would like to apply the filter not only based on the action name but on the format of the request. In other words, I would like to do something like this:

```
before_filter :login_required, :except => {:action => :index, :format => :js}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You'll need to roll your own a bit.  Try this as a starting point.

```
 before_filter :login_required, :except => [:index]

 before_filter(:only => :index) do |controller|
   login_required unless controller.request.format.js?
 end
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I only had to replace the login_required with controller.send(:login_required)

  before_filter(:only => :index) do |controller|
    controller.send(:login_required) unless controller.request.format.js?
  end

Comment: Let me repeat my comment as the code didn't show up as I was expecting.

I only had to replace the login_required with controller.send(:login_required) 

Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

Remember, you can extract the lambda to a method too. This can help with readability. It can also make it easier to use the same check on multiple filters.

```
before_filter :login_required, except: :index, unless: :js_request?

private

def js_request?
  request.format.js?
end
```

Answer (score 13):

Another way, which I think is cleaner than the accepted answer, is to use the `if` or `unless` options with a lambda. I just like having the method name listed as a symbol so it's standardized with the other controller filters. This works in Rails 3 and up.

```
before_filter :login_required, except: :index,
  unless: ->(controller) { controller.request.format.js? }
```