# Rails 4 - Json rendering without authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am new to RoR. So far in my project, I worked with `Devise` gem for authentication. All work's fine. But I want to get `json` unauthentic access for API on `index`. I tried little bit for that.

In my `Application Controller`.

```
class ApplicationCotroller < Action Controller::Base
   protect_from_forgery_with :exception, :null_session => true 
   before_action :authenticate_user!, except: :index
end
```

This is my `Product Controller index`.

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: :index, if: -> { request.format.json? }
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

   def index
      @products = Product.all
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { render json: @products}
      end
   end
```

When I request to get `json`

```
http://localhost:3000/products.json
```

It works fine. even this will load also the `UI index` page.

I need only to check if it is `JSON` request comes.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, if: :skip_authenticate_user

  def index 
    ...
  end

  protected
    def skip_authenticate_user
      action_name=='index'  && (request.format.json? || request.format.xml?)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding [`skip_before_action`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-skip_before_action) in your `ProductsController`:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: :index

  def index 
    ...
  end
end
```

This will ensure that the `authentication_user!` method is skipped for `ProductsController` `index` action.

Comment: Is this only for `JSON request`?

Comment: This explains how to do this just for a specific format: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809528/before-filter-and-respond-to-formats

Comment: @Ranjith, this answer does not check for `JSON` request format. Try using `skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: :index, if: -> {request.format.json? }`

Comment: @vee. I tried. It works fine, now the problem is view page also shown. I think doesn't check this `if: -> {request.format.json? }` condition

Comment: @vee Now I got JSON when i'm request like this `http://localhost:3000/products.json`, but its also unauthentic for `UI view` page when I request from this one `http://localhost:3000/products`