# How do I access user data in the active records of rails in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I want to pull the locations of users from the active record in javascript. I want to then load this data somehow into javascript,  and then load this data onto a map. However, I am not able to get this data into javascript. I previously used Jbuilder to create a JSON link as such:

index.json.builder of user

```
json.user @usersall do |user|
    json.name user.name
    json.id user.id
    json.lat  user.lat
    json.long user.long
end
```

I can access that data at localhost:3000/users.json, and parse it in javascript from there. The problem is normal users are able to access this JSON too (Users can now see where other people live). Also, I want people not logged in to be able to see this map, yet be unable to access the JSON also. So it looks like JSON is not going to work. What can I do to access the data securely?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809528/before-filter-and-respond-to-formats You can have a filter in your `before_action` that uses a conditional. Just change the condition in that answer to `login_required if controller.request.format.json?`

Comment: The login is already required. The problem is that I want people not logged in to be able to see a map with markers on it (no information given of names, just markers) of locations, and they still need access to the JSON request to be able to see markers, but if they do they can see all the sensitive user data. I'm looking for another way to access the data and use it in javascript.

Comment: Hmm, you could check in the index action for if a user is logged in, and set `@usersall` based on that, `@usersall = Users.all.select("lat, long")` Of course, your JSON would need to account for the chance that there won't be an id, or name in that situation.